# log4net oracle doesn't work

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I made a log4net project with WinForm about keeping logs in the database. I contacted SQL Server and wrote logs here. But when I try to contact to Oracle and save log in Oracle database, it didn't work. Why? I am sure the connection string is correct, but it does not work. Is there something wrong with the connection string or is there something else I need to implement for Oracle?

Here is my Log4net.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigrationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="All"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_Oracle"></appender-ref>
    </root>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender_Oracle" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess,Version=2.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <connectionString value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MYHOST)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MYDBNAME)));User Id=MYUSERID;Password=MYPASSWORD;" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log (Datetime,Thread,Log_Level,Logger,Message) VALUES (:log_date, :thread, :log_level, :logger, :message)" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide any error messages or logfiles?

Comment: No, i dont get any error message.When I change log4net config with sql server settings its log correctly to sql server db.

Comment: [Enable internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) and see if it tells you something useful.

Comment: Thanks alot @JeroenMostert and FabianSchöner for your answers.I change the 

 <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess,Version=2.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /> 

with 

      <connectionType value="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>

Ant it run correctly and log to oracle values.